# week function giving strange result

Tags: sas

using the week function to clean some data and eventually will order the weeks.  I used week() on the date 8/26/2011 and I got 34, and when the function inserted the date 01/13/2012 it spit out 2. I thouhgt I was getting number of weeks since jan 1, 1960?

Answer (score 1):

As per the [WEEK Function documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003154994.htm), the default `U` descriptor specifies the number of the week **within the year**, with Sunday being deemed the 1st day of the week. (You can use `V` if you want Monday to be considered the 1st day instead.)

Comment: I don't think this answers his admittedly confusingly worded question - he's not asking about date start, he's asking about weeks-since-X-time.

Answer (score 1):

The `week` function calculates the week of the *current* year.  The answer to the implied question, "how do I calculated the number of days since 1/1/1960 [or some arbitrary date]," is the `intck` function.

```
data have;
input datevar date9.;
datalines;
01JAN1960
02JAN2013
13JAN2012
26AUG2011
;;;;
run;
data want;
set have;
wks = intck('week',0,datevar); *# of weeks from 0 to datevar [0=1/1/1960]. 
                               *Can replace 0 with any other date variable.;
run;
```